# Launch a file with command line arguments without knowing location of exe?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Here's the situation: I am trying to launch an application, but the location of the .exe isn't known to me.  Now, if the file extension is registered (in Windows), I can do something like:

```
Process.Start("Sample.xls");
```

However, I need to pass some command line arguments as well.  I couldn't get this to work

```
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "Sample.xls";
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r";  // open in read-only mode
   p.Start();
```

Any suggestions on a mechanism to solve this?

**Edit** @ aku

My StackOverflow search skills are weak; I did not find that post.  Though I generally dislike peering into the registry, that's a great solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using my code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954/windows-list-and-launch-applications-associated-with-an-extension#24974) answer you can get command associated with xls extension. Then you can pass this command to `Process.Start` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you query the registry, you can retrieve the data about the registered file type and then call the app directly passing the command line arguments.  See [Programmatically Checking and Setting File Types](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ProgrammaticFileTypes.aspx) for an example of retrieving shell information for a file type.