# How to get installed applications install folder(path) and uninstaller

Tags: c#, windows, registry, uninstallation

Hello I need some way of finding all the insllaled applications on windows(I already found the names but i need the actual folder). Also I need the path to their uninstaller.
I'm trying to build an application that is similar with Advanced Uninstaller pro.
PS. I need to do this in C#.

Comment: Its looks a duplicate post and check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909910/how-to-find-the-execution-path-of-a-installed-software

Comment: @Achayan though it's a way different from what's in the link you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wont need the path to the installer, you have to get the UninstallString value for each installed application so you can excute it once wanted to be removed. All of them are available here : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (my case is 64bit system)
You can enumerate all apps from here by getting DisplayName value. 
 Hope it helps