# How do I launch files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, shell

-Edit- I feel like an idiot. I had a feeling something like the answer below would work but didn't see any google results similar to the answers below. So when I saw this complex code I thought it had to be this way.

I searched and found this [Windows: List and Launch applications associated with an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954/windows-list-and-launch-applications-associated-with-an-extension) however it didn't answer my question. With tweaks below, I came up with the below. However, it gets stuck on image files. Txt files run fine

I will update this code soon to account for app paths with spaces however I don't understand why image files don't launch.

```
static void launchFile(string fn)
{
    //majority was taken from
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954/windows-list-and-launch-applications-associated-with-an-extension
    const string extPathTemplate = @"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{0}";
    const string cmdPathTemplate = @"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{0}\shell\open\command";

    string ext = Path.GetExtension(fn);

    var extPath = string.Format(extPathTemplate, ext);

    var docName = Registry.GetValue(extPath, string.Empty, string.Empty) as string;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(docName))
    {
        // 2. Find out which command is associated with our extension
        var associatedCmdPath = string.Format(cmdPathTemplate, docName);
        var associatedCmd = Registry.GetValue(associatedCmdPath, string.Empty, string.Empty) as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(associatedCmd))
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" command is associated with {1} extension", associatedCmd, ext);
            var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = associatedCmd.Split(' ')[0];
            string s2 = associatedCmd.Substring(p.StartInfo.FileName.Length + 1);
            s2 = s2.Replace("%1", string.Format("\"{0}\"", fn));
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = s2;//string.Format("\"{0}\"", fn);
            p.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens with those image files if you trying writing whatever the resulting debug statement is for them just on the command line?

Comment: do you just want to launch files in Windows?

Answer (score 118):

Use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```

It will use the default program that would be opened as if you just clicked on it. Admittedly it doesn't let you choose the program that will run... but assuming that you want to mimic the behaviour that would be used if the user were to double-click on the file, this should work just fine.

Comment: how about you wanted to open it with a specific program, I want to open it with "Windows PowerShell ISE"

Comment: on windows 10 and .net 5 i got this error: "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"

Comment: @HamidZ the program associated with that file does not exist or is invalid.

Comment: For those who are facing above error with this, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46808516/5436341

Answer (score 14):

It really sounds like you're looking more for this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "<whatever>";
proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you just want to launch files which already have some associated applications (eg: *.txt is associated with notepad),
Use System.Diagnostics.Process.

e.g. :

```
 using System.Diagnostics;
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    pi.UseShellExecute = true;
    pi.FileName = @"MY_FILE_WITH_FULL_PATH.jpg";
    p.StartInfo = pi;

    try
    {
        p.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
    }
```

Note: In my PC, the pic opens in Windows Picture & Fax Viewer since that is the default application for *.jpg files.

Answer (score 1):

For me at least, using DotNet 5+ / Dotnet Core the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start doesn't work (on Windows 10 or 11). So I used the ShellExecute API instead.

Call the below code by using

ShellExecute("***filename***");

eg.
ShellExecute("c:\temp\test.txt");

**C# code for the method:**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;     
[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
        private static extern int ShellExecuteA(IntPtr hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, string lpParameters, string lpDirecotry, int nShowCmd);

    public static int ShellExecute(string filename, string parameters = "", string workingFolder = "", string verb = "open", int windowOption = 1)
    {
        //calls Windows ShellExecute API
        //for verbs see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch (open/edit/runas...)
        //for windowOptions see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow (show/hide/maximize etc)

        IntPtr parentWindow = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            int pid = ShellExecuteA(parentWindow, verb, filename, parameters, workingFolder, windowOption);
            return pid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return 0;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it still popped up for me and it seems like it's due for an update in case others are finding it.  For Windows 11 I'd be looking into [Windows.System.Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync?view=winrt-22621), here's more of a [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file).

```
async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Path to the file in the app package to launch
   string imageFile = @"images\test.png";

   var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);

   if (file != null)
   {
      // Launch the retrieved file
      var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

      if (success)
      {
         // File launched
      }
      else
      {
         // File launch failed
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Could not find file
   }
}
```