# How to open a generic file?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I need a way to open a generic file with the **default application for that file**.

For example: if the file is an HTML file, then it will be opened with Internet Explorer; if the file is an image (JPG, BMP, etc.), then it will be opened with "Paint"; if the file is an MP3 file, then it will be opened with Windows Media Player.

How can I do this ? What function or API do I have to use ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i launch files in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283584/how-do-i-launch-files-in-c)

Comment: @abelenky This is for C++ or C and NOT for C# :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the ShellExecute function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx

EDIT: or [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Or better yet, ShellExecuteEx.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use standard `system` function - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/ so you won't even need to depend on WinAPI.

E.g.: `system("start <filename>");`