# In C# how does one make a file load in its correct program?

Tags: c#, openxml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i launch files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283584/how-do-i-launch-files-in-c-sharp)

I mean say having a word document and running a function to open it in microsoft word etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path to document")` will start the default handler for that document type.

Comment: Mark it as the accepted answer then ;) http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask