# C# Windows form Application With PowerShell Automation Commands Restrictions

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to create an app that would setup bitlocker PIN Programmatically.

the app works as well as the PowerShell Command, However, I am unfortunately unable to execute it.

I am getting the following Error when Executing:

"Application Attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required permissions, contact your system administrator or use Microsoft .Net Configuration Tool"

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (PIN.Text.Length < 20)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Passwords must be at least 20 characters long.");
                return;
            }
             else if (PIN2.Text != PIN.Text)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Password & Confirmation are not identical, Please ensure that both Passwords are the same");
                 return;
             }
             else
             {
                 PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
                 ps.AddCommand("$PIN = \"" + PIN.Text + "\" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force; Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint \"C:\" -PIN $PIN -TPMAndPinProtector -SkipHardwareTest");
                 ps.Invoke();
                 MessageBox.Show("Your Pre-Boot PIN has now been Setup - Please reboot after 30 Minutes and login with your PIN");
                 Application.Exit();
```

I have set assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1) but issue remains.

is it a GPO that would need to be amended at all? or would i be able to bypass in the App somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making an actual PowerShell script file and then running the file?

[take a look at this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-your-first-powershell-script-file-windows-10)

Comment: In general: While the linked page may answer the question, it is [better to include the essential parts _here_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248777) and provide the link only for reference / additional information. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page disappears or changes substantially. If you can only offer a link, please consider posting it as a _comment_ rather than as an answer (requires 15 or more reputation points, however).

Comment: Hello there and thank you, runing the ps1 script file works, however i need to hard code it into the app and use the textbox values to set a pin

Comment: Well I mean you can try writing the command as plain text (using IO streams I guess) into a file and then save the file with "name.ps1" as filePath (it will be saved on the executable directory) and then running the file like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283584/how-do-i-launch-files-in-c-sharp/1283593

Comment: btw have you tried running your app as administrator?

Comment: Ahh understodd, Unfortunately this is not possible as we are unable to save any form of files into the machines that contain passwords so that is why i am trying to run a dynamic code to do it, and yes, running as Administrator does not work either unfortunately