# How to get installed image editors

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a code to get all the image editing software the user has installed?
I would like to know how to list all the applications by going through registry, is there any way to then filter out only the apps that can edit images, like Paint, Photoshop, etc...?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a list of programs you'd like to look for?  There's not going to be anything like an `image-editor` tag or anything in the registry.

Comment: One way would be to enumerate the shell file extension handlers, e.g., the list of apps you see when you select a an image file and choose "Open with..."

Comment: I suggested the edit of the title. See [Should questions include tags in their titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for any generic file type:

[How to get recommended programs associated with file extension in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679385/how-to-get-recommended-programs-associated-with-file-extension-in-c-sharp)

If you look for jpg, png, etc. you'll get image editors.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no expectation that every application developer somehow places metadata tags for their application inside of the registry (or wherever)... and, if for some reaosn a few handful of application developers did there is no way to guarantee the consistancy. Not to mention that application developers don't always use the common words you'd expect for their applications... Not every image editing application has the word "Photo" in it (for example, [`Picasa`](http://picasa.google.com/) from Google).

The best you can hope for is to build some keywords to look for, add in a list of famous applications that don't conform to the keyword conventions your expecting ("Paint", "Photo", "Image", etc.), and work with that... either that or create a large database yourself to check against. Also, as other answers/comments have indicated, looking for applications that are used for specific extensions is helpful.

Nothing guaranteed though.