# Catch opening of file if there's no program to open it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf, registry

my code

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
info.WorkingDirectory = path;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
var p = Process.Start(info);
```

it will open a file (.pdf, but could be another type of file later)
In some cases, there's no program installed for open it, so it shows me the windows message

> Windows can't open this file

and offers me to search some program to open it.

How can I avoid this?
I want to show another message. In `try/catch` it doesn't throw any kind of exceptions, so its not working.

I tried, if is only .pdf to detect if there is any program installed with this

```
var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(".pdf");
if(key != null)
//  Not installed!
```

but it's not working. I'm getting a key, but I've uninstalled Foxit reader (and also I've use CCleaner to remove conflicts key, but still have .pdf key)

Please help

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679385/how-to-get-recommended-programs-associated-with-file-extension-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [FindExecutable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, **but** the file being checked must actually exist:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr FindExecutable(string lpFile, string lpDirectory, StringBuilder lpResult);

    private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\Mike\Documents\SomeFile.xyz";
        string EXE = GetAssociatedExecutable(path);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EXE))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EXE, "Associated Executable");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Asssociated Executable for: " + path);
        }
    }

    private string GetAssociatedExecutable(string filename)
    {
        const int MAX_PATH = 260;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
            FindExecutable(filename, null, sb);
            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```