# How do you open a file on a server using different user account credentials

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-4.0, filesystems

I'm currently developing a C# WinForms application in VS2012 (.NET 4.0). The application is a bit like an Email client and displays a list of messages. And each message can have one or one files attached. 
The file attachments are stored on a different server, which can only be accessed using another user account (and not by the logged on user).

When the user double clicks on a File Attachment I need to open the file and display it in the associated application. i.e. TXT files in Notepad, DOCX files in Word, etc.

I was hoping I could just pass the full file name into the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method, with the correct username, password and domain values and it would open the file in the associated application.
e.g.

```
SecureString password = new SecureString();
"MyPassword".ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(password.AppendChar);

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\MyServer\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyFile.docx",
                                 "MyUsername",
                                 password,
                                 "MyDomain");
```

But an exception is thrown with the message:
The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

I've also tried creating a `ProcessStartInfo` object instance and setting the `FileName` property to `"Explorer.exe"` and the `Arguments` property to `@"\\MyServer\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyFile.docx"`, and passing it as the parameter into the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method. But this doesn't work either. No exception is thrown and the file isn't displayed either.

But if you look at the object returned by the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method you see that an `InvalidOperationException` has occurred.

My C# question is, how can I open and display a file (in it's associated application), when the file is stored on a server that can only be accessed using different user credentials?

Comment: It seems to like this is hard to do because you shouldn't be doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

Step 1. Find the App registered with the extension
Step 2. Use the same Api that was mentioned 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("App from the current Machine that was found in step 1",
@"\MyServer\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyFile.docx",
                                 "MyUsername",
                                 password,
                                 "MyDomain");

See the following links of how to find the register app for an extension

[How to get recommended programs associated with file extension in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679385/how-to-get-recommended-programs-associated-with-file-extension-in-c-sharp)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17023/System-File-Association