# How we can show list of supported application for playing video file by c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, combobox

I want to display list of supported application for playing video file in combobox in windows application c#; Which is available in user computer like VLC, wmp, KMplayer, zoomplayer etc... Then user will choose his/her favorite player before clicking on play button.

Comment: You could enumerate the software installed, and filter for known applications. Then check the registry/etc for the path/etc to each of the programs.  Check with each application what the launch parameters are.

Comment: @KraangPrime plz help me by code.

Comment: [List applications installed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/908907/3504007) .   The rest, you will need to research each application you wish to support. You could go by standards and use the user selected default - much easier:  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\path\to\movie.mpg");`

Comment: @KraangPrime Thanks for helping me and also for nice suggestion but i try to give my best so i am trying to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get recommended programs associated with file extension in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679385/how-to-get-recommended-programs-associated-with-file-extension-in-c-sharp)